# SQL Server Backup Job failed multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I am getting the same error as mentioned by Mr.Ali

[Sql Server Backup Job failed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64135/sql-server-backup-job-failed)

Can anyone please explain the possible ways to fix this error as the backup is failing since 1 month.

Here is the Job history log

```
Executed as user: SAP\sqladmin.
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
Started:  21:00:00
Progress: 2014-10-03 21:00:05.83
Source: {E7436186-D15A-4485-92B4-7623DA7DDF4D}
Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete
End
Progress
Error: 2014-10-03 23:32:25.53
Code: 0xC002F210    
Source: Back Up Database Task Execute SQL Task
Description:
Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [P01] TO  DISK =N'\\cmgsap31.sap...."
failed with the following error:
"Write on "\\cmgsap31.sap.logica.com\p$\Central-MS-SQL-Backup\SAP0233_P01_Full.bkp"
failed: 64(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) 
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
80 percent processed.". 
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
"ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
or connection not established correctly.
End Error 
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started: 21:00:00
Finished: 23:32:25
Elapsed:  9145.29 seconds.
The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398385/sql-server-2008-backup-error-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text

Comment: @user51250, OS error 64 is "The specified network name is no longer available." There is something happens with the connection during the backup. Do you have enough space to make the backup to the local drive and then try copying to the remote location?

Answer (score 1):

Well based on Reason:15105 I think that SQL Server doesn't have permission to access to the path you check the permissions of the account that is assigned to the SQL service account? or other reason would be that there is not enough free space to create backup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anjana.I have checked the permissions of the user account. It has the access and there is 80+ GB free space in the disk so i think this may not be the problem as well. Any other possible reasons?

Comment: @user51250 Is it possible that there is problem accessing the network path? \\cmgsap31.sap.logica.com\p$\Central-MS-SQL-Backup\

Comment: @user51250 Try Starting the SQL Management Studio "As Administrator."and execute the job may be its the fact that SQL Management Studio must be having a issue accessing the Path.

Comment: Yes we are starting the SQL Management Studio as Administrator only, even though we are getting the same error. We tried accessing the path from our server it is working fine with no issues.Any OS related problems for this?

Comment: @user51250 Try Setting the SessTimeout value in the registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters to a higher value. 300 
is suggested 45 should be the default Value,After Applying the registry Value chage make sure reboot the SQL Server

Comment: @user51250 *you* being able to access the network path is not the same as the SQL Server service being able to access the network path. Also if you have a flaky network with intermittent connection issues, just because you can connect now doesn't mean SQL Server could connect at that time (or stay connected throughout).

Comment: @Anjana where should i set this parameter? In the present server? or where the share is located?

Comment: @AaronBertrand u mean issue is because of network?

Comment: @user51250 I have no idea. I'm saying it's possible.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ok then what is the possible fix for this?. You may be correct because backups finished successfully in the previous month but we are facing the issue from the past 4 weeks

Comment: Having had poor network quality in the past (and run into the same problem) we set up a drive on the server and did backups to the local drive, then used a file copy to move the backup files to the new location.  It's not the best method but it works.

Comment: And it took you four weeks to do something about it?

Comment: @KennethFisher will try in your way. hope that helps

Comment: Sorry for the Late Reply @user51250 You should do this in your present server

Answer (score 1):

This is a network timeout issue.  You can troubleshoot this with your network team or by running a network packet trace that is filtered to SMB traffic between the SQL Server and the destination file server.  A word of caution, this trace will be intensive with the tools that I am recommending and I have had mixed success with them (I last used it in an environment where I did not have a dedicated network team) and can cause network problems so choose a high performance filter to perform these traces and proceed with caution.  What you will likely see when you examine the capture is that during one of the final commands you run into a network latency issue that causes a timeout which results in the backup failure you see.  To work around this you will need to tune the SMB shares to not timeout as quickly especially if you are dealing with a large backup and a slow network.

I've used NetMon in the past and had good luck at capturing this type of data.  You will need to confirm the ports in use on your network but they should be UDP 137 and 138 and TCP 137 and 138 for SMB traffic.  From here you will need to write a filter that captures only traffic that has a source of your SQL Server or the file share and destination of the same.  I highly recommend some reading on high performance filters with NetMon as this utility does have overhead involved and can cause packet loss or odd performance issues which may result in an inability to reproduce the issue. I would also suggest a rolling capture as it will be unlikely that you require all of the data captured but instead just the last several frames.

There appears to be an updated version of NetMon which is now called Message Analyzer but I have no familiarity with this product so I cannot speak for any issues that may result or compatibility with the product.

I hope that I have provided you with at least a place to start and possibly some ideas for how to troubleshoot this issue.  Given that you have a network stack in the middle there are any number of reasons why you may be seeing this problem.  I would highly recommend that you seek out your network team if you have one and see if they can guide you further.  Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

This issue usually occur if you have a third-party backups and it might be breaking Log chain. I have came across the same problem at my work. Everyday, there are working fine but we had a third party backup at 9 pm and the backups fail for next 4 hours, then 1 am diff backup is done fine. I resolved this issue by moving third party backups from Database and disk level.