# SQL Server - BackupDiskFile - Referencing to deleted TR Backup file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, backup

We have a backup job which creates transaction log backups every 10 mins for databases. Backup files which older than 2 days are deleted.

In ERRORLOG file - I see the record which I cannot get/understand:

---

```
        2021-09-21 00:37:07.14 spid91      BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '\\ncxxx01\db2_backup_2021_09_19_003702_3012358.trn' failed to open. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
        2021-09-21 01:52:03.18 spid143     BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '\\ncxxx01\db2_backup_2021_09_19_013702_0869640.trn' failed to open. Operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.).
        2021-09-21 03:52:03.50 spid144     BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '\\ncxxx01\db2_backup_2021_09_19_035201_2656433.trn' failed to open. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
        2021-09-21 04:52:03.41 spid148     BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '\\ncxxx01\db2_backup_2021_09_19_045201_7349687.trn' failed to open. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
        2021-09-21 07:07:03.68 spid141     BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '\\ncxxx01\db2_backup_2021_09_19_065201_4134816.trn' failed to open. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
```

---

My question is why SQL Server points it as error in log file as we have Backup jobs which does backup and other job which deletes files older than 2 days? If SQL Server somehow references to deleted Transactional backup file? Note: The path is correct.

Sorry for format of post, but I did not find hints for formatting log records.

With regards!

Comment: Have you checked whether or not the file exists? Based on the timestamps, it might be the task that deletes files that caused this, when it attempted to remove the file, but found it wasn't there. Is it somehow possible the job executed more than once, or someone manually deleted or moved the file? Is there third party software accessing the backup files at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Server Backup Job failed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64135/sql-server-backup-job-failed)  In addition to the permissions raised in the attached answer, flaky network connectivity to a network share can also cause intermittent "Operating system error 2" failures on backup.

Comment: My guess is that the job has "verify backup on completion" and the RESTORE VERIFYONLY doesn't find the file. I.e., the backup command produces the file and it immediately is removed for some reason. It shouldn't be a permissions problem, since that would give a different OS code. Furthermore, Agent permissions does definitely not come into play since it is the db engine that accesses the file (not agent).

Comment: Hi guys, many thanks for your help.
I followed your recommendation and checked the details of job.
It is the Backup Maintenance Plan running every 15 min which has 2 tasks 1) Backup trans log of database (with enabled option 'Verify backup integrity') 2) Connected task -> Delete backup trn file older than 2 days

Comment: Also, I forgot to add that above pointed Maintenance Plan job operates from AlwaysOn HA from 2 nodes to the same location (shared storage). OK, understood that they are conflicting to each other. Let's say 01A and 01B, work schedule is the same.  And 01B job deletes files older than 2 days. But why SQL (due to above log records) tries to open deleted TRN files (in ERRORLOG in 01A)? I cannot get it.